# Create link to folder in Elementary-OS

Tags: files, elementary-os

When I used to use stock Ubuntu, you could create links to folders and put them in other folders. How can I do this in elementary 0.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about symbolic links?

You use the command:

```
% ln -s <folder to link> <folder>
```

for example:

```
% ln -s /home/sam/dirtolink /home/sam/linktodir
```

See the man page for [ln](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/214/170): just drag the file or folder you want to link & drop it where you need the link **with the right-click** to have a list of options: *Copy*, *Move* or ***Create link***.